# Jedox - How to export SOAP Log into Excel file

Tags: vba, logging, soap, jedox

I'm pretty new on Jedox, and I'm trying for internal use to export some specific "warning logs" (eg. "(*Mapping missing*)" ) into an excel/wss file.

And I don't how to do that...

Can you help me please.

Regards,
Usik

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get these information is to use the **Integrator** in Jedox.
There you have the possibility to use a File Extract and then you can filter the information you are searching for.
After that it's possible to load these filtered information into a File.
The minimum steps you'll need are Connection -> Extract -> Transform -> Load.
Please take a look at the sample projects that are delivered with the Jedox software. In the example "sampleBiker", there are also file connections, extracts etc.
You can find more samples in:

```
<Install_path>\tomcat\webapps\etlserver\data\samples
```

I recommend to check the [Jedox Knowledgebase](http://knowledgebase.jedox.com).

The other way (and maybe more flexible way) would be to use, for example, a PHP macro inside of a Jedox Web report and read the log file you're trying to display.
If you've got a more specific idea what you'd like to do, please let me know and I'll try to give you an example how to do so.

Comment: Starting an answer with a question is a good way to get it downvoted and deleted. I removed that part since it seems like the answer might be otherwise valid. If that information is relevant to your answer, you may want to try to avoid phrasing it as a question (e.g. state your assumptions - "on the assumption..., you can..."). Alternatively, a better option might be to post a comment on your own answer mentioning these issues in a "I'm not sure my answer is correct" kind of way (if that's what it was). Getting that 50 reputation and then asking and waiting for clarification is best though.